# MyBatis Spring DYNAMIC number of multiple databases Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

This is fairly straight forward with a simple Spring DAO approach. However, using MyBatis, is there a way to setup multiple potential datasources?

The best approach I can think of is to use an ArraList of a Bean each containing datasource.driverclass,datasource.url, datasource.username, datasource.password etc.

The values for the datasources are stored in individual properties files. There could be 1 or 10 of these property files (or more).

So for example, one application startup all the property files would be loaded one at a time into an ArrayList. Then, based on the NAME=value line from the property file, we would know which datasource to hit.

So http:localhost:8080/name=db1

... would access all the data from the datasource configured with the name "09". Each property file would contain:

```
name=db1
datasource.driverclass=jdbc:sqlserver
datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=someDBname
datasource.username=user1
datasource.password=pass1
```

So the identifier here is "name=db1".

Would the best approach from a MyBatis implementation utilise an ArrayList of Beans?

Comment: Are you looking to provide multitenancy? If so, there's probably a way better  solution than trying to roll your own like that.

Comment: please, edit your question to tell us more about the context, what are you trying to achieve? why are you using multiple datasources? all with same scheme? same data?

Comment: @Kayaman - that's exactly the plan, a multitenant solution. Any suggestions that you feel would work better in that situation?

Comment: @blackwizard - I'll add some details above. Basically a multitenant solution, different data/database and same schema.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd find something by googling "mybatis multitenancy".

Comment: I read multi-tenancy is resources mutualization, here you want to mutualize the App but not the DB. Beware: maintaining N database could become tedious. There is only 1 schema , then why not using a single DB and queries like `WHERE tenantId=#{tenantId}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a hierarchical application.yml file detailing the multitenant connection values, based on a selected tenant code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some leads if you want to keep up with multiple DB:

Anyway, I would say datasources shall be managed in the server confiquration instead of in the App.

Then Mybatis main configuration file must be placed in a location added to the classpath, but outside of the app package, because every new datasource must be referenced there inside an *environment* element.

And for every user request or session (in case of a web app), the configuration will be parsed because `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(reader, environment=NAME);` must be called to choose the environment (=> the DB).